# Convert tricky linq expression to SQL

Tags: sql, linq

I have following linq expression:

```
        var files = posts
            .Select(post => int.Parse(post.Length.ToString()[0].ToString()))
            .GroupBy(c => c)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

I want to translate it to SQL (Microsoft SQL). Where `source` is `IEnumerable<string>`. The problem is how to group records by it's first digit and count quantity of items in each group.

The database has one table `Posts`, that has column `Body`(`varchar(max)`). I'm interested in first digit of it's length.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT firstDigit as Key, COUNT(*) as theCount
FROM
(
  SELECT convert(int, LEFT(convert(varchar(30), f), 1)) as firstDigit
  FROM Source as f
) as sub
GROUP BY firstDigit
```